# Use MsBuild scripts in TeamCity to run Sonar Scanner for MsBuild

Tags: c#, sonarqube, teamcity, sonarqube-scan

I am upgrading TeamCity 2017.1.4 and SonarQube 6.7.1 and am upgrading the analysis method to use the Sonar Scanner for MsBuild (4.0.2) rather than the Sonar Runner which was used previously.

We use MsBuild scripts so that we can source control the changes and I am struggling to get the Sonar Scanner to work.

The problem appears to be when I use the MSBuild task to build the project Sonar complains stating that it hasn't been built or was not built with a newer version of MsBuild.
Yet, if I specify the build using a Exec command it processes everything correctly.

Using Exec to run MsBuild (not what I want to do):

```
<Exec Command="$(SonarScannerMSBuildPath) begin /d:sonar.verbose=$(SonarScannerVerboseLogging) /k:&quot;$(SonarProjectKey)&quot; /n:&quot;$(SonarProjectName)&quot; /v:&quot;$(Build_Number)&quot;" />  
<Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe&quot; @(Solution)  /t:Rebuild" />
<Exec Command="$(SonarScannerMSBuildPath) end" />
```

The commands I'd like to use is, as this should use the version of MsBuild selected in TeamCity:

```
<Exec Command="$(SonarScannerMSBuildPath) begin /d:sonar.verbose=$(SonarScannerVerboseLogging) /k:&quot;$(SonarProjectKey)&quot; /n:&quot;$(SonarProjectName)&quot; /v:&quot;$(Build_Number)&quot;" />  
<MSBuild Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Configuration=Debug" Projects="@(Solution)" />
<Exec Command="$(SonarScannerMSBuildPath) end" />
```

In TeamCity I have the MsBuild version set as:
[image: MsBuild2017Configuration]

I have noticed that when I run the Exec command to build the solution I see the Analyzer warnings but these don't appear when the build is run via the MsBuild command.
The teamcity output implies that the correct MsBuild version is being used:

```
[11:40:34]  [Step 1/1] Starting: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MsBuildBootstrap.exe /workdir:D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\488e6f245ac98af3 "/msbuildPath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin\MSBuild.exe"
```

The error information states:

```
[12:23:07]  [Exec] The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
[12:23:07]  [Exec] Possible causes:
[12:23:07]  [Exec] 1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
[12:23:07]  [Exec] 2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 upwards are supported
[12:23:07]  [Exec] 3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
```

If I browse to the folder on the TeamCity build agent I am missing the .sonar and .sonarqube folders.

Answer (score 1):

I could recommend using plain Commnand line runner in TeamCity to run SonarQube Scanner. You can set up working directory there without problem. Here is an example of my custom script:

```
"%sonar.scanner.msbuild%\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe" begin^
 /k:"ProjectKey"^
 /n:"ProjectName"^
 /v:"%build.vcs.number%.%build.counter%"
"%MSBuildTools15.0_x64_Path%\MSBuild.exe" SolutionFile.sln /t:Rebuild
"%sonar.scanner.msbuild%\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe" end
```

Where

> %sonar.scanner.msbuild%

is my custom parameter - full path to SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe, and

> %MSBuildTools15.0_x64_Path%

is parameter from TeamCity pointing to Visual Studio 2017 Build tools.

My working directory is set up to

> %teamcity.build.checkoutDir%

Print screen of the whole configuration:

[image]

Comment: This was similar to the solution I came up with.  Using MsBuild scripts I had to create an environment variable (which I called MSBuildTools15_0_x86_Path) which was set to %MSBuildTools15.0_x86_Path%.  Then in my build script I referenced it via     <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildTools15_0_x86_Path)\msbuild.exe&quot; @(Solution)  /t:Rebuild" />

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner for MSBuild expects the *begin*, *build*, and *end* steps to be run from the same directory. My guess is that the *Exec* and *MSBuild* tasks are using different working directories.

You could try setting the *WorkingDirectory* parameter of the *Exec* task to see if that helps (I'd try setting it to the directory containing the solution first).

Comment: I think this could be the reason but I'm still struggling.  I have added WorkingDirectory to the begin and end steps and have used the directory of the .sln file but I still get the same error.  I'm thinking that I need to set the folder for the MsBuild step as the .sln file is a couple of folders deep in the TeamCity workdir but there isn't a WorkingFolder parameter to the MsBuild task.

Comment: You could try running the MSBuild with diagnostic verbosity and checking the value of the reserved property $(MSBuildStartupDirectory) - that might be the "working directory" that you need to set.

Comment: I can only set the verbosity when I run MsBuild from an Exec task.  The variable is available and I've tried setting the Begin and End tasks to start in that folder, sadly I still get the same error.